lvextend + use variable in order to lvextend filesystem
we have different Linux machines and each Linux machine need different partition size
in order to extend the root filesystem or var filesystem by script , we can use the following lvextend syntax , with variable as - PARTITION_VAL_SIZE
 PARTITION_VAL_SIZE=100
 lvextend -L"$PARTITION_VAL_SIZE"G /dev/vg-data/lv-var
 PARTITION_VAL_SIZE=30
 lvextend -L"$PARTITION_VAL_SIZE"G /dev/vg-data/lv-root
 .
 .
 PARTITION_VAL_SIZE=50
 lvextend -L"$PARTITION_VAL_SIZE"G /dev/vg-data/lv-var
 PARTITION_VAL_SIZE=20
 lvextend -L"$PARTITION_VAL_SIZE"G /dev/vg-data/lv-root

 .
 .

because we are using values in GIGA then we add the "G" on lvextend command
can we do it better ? or is our approach is good enough in order to increase Linux partition with variable ?

Checking the documentation using man lvextend,

-L|--size [+]Size[m|UNIT] Specifies the new size of the LV. The --size and --extents options are alternate methods of specifying size. […]               When the plus + or minus - prefix is used, the value is not an absolute size, but is relative and added or subtracted from the current size.

Also from the same page,

Size[UNIT] Size is an input number that accepts an optional unit. Input units are always treated as base two values […]. UNIT represents other possible input units: […] g|G is GiB […].

So, when you write:
PARTITION_VAL_SIZE=100
lvextend -L"$PARTITION_VAL_SIZE"G /dev/vg-data/lv-var

You should know that the shell will expand this to:
lvextend -L100G /dev/vg-data/lv-var

And this means resize the partition to 100 Gibibytes. It does not mean extend the partition by a further 100 Gibibytes. For that you would need to use
lvextend -L +100G /dev/vg-data/lv-var

Remember that GiB > GB, but if you're already thinking of sizes in terms of 2n rather than 10n you'll be fine.
As a preference, I'd recommend using --size here instead of -L. It's the same thing but easier to read:
lvextend --size 100G /dev/vg-data/lv-var

